# How to get two arrays JSON response in android

Tags: php, android, json

I don't know how to get my JSON response in android.

**JSON response:**

```
{
  "client_id": ["1", "3", "4", "4"],
  "payed": ["0", "1", "1", "1"]
}
```

P.S: payed is a boolean.

**PHP file:**

```
$statement = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT client_id,Payed FROM reservations WHERE resto_id = '$restaurantID'");

$response = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($statement)){
    $response["client_id"][]=$row["client_id"];
    $response["payed"][]=$row["Payed"];
}         

echo json_encode($response);
```

I tried to get the response like this, but it doesn't work:

```
Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
    public void onResponse(String response) {
    System.out.println(response);
    try {
        JSONArray jsonResponse = new JSONArray(response);
        System.out.println("JSON LENGTH =" + jsonResponse.length());

        String[] clients = new String[jsonResponse.length()];
        Boolean[] status = new Boolean[jsonResponse.length()];

        for (int i = 0; i < jsonResponse.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject obj = jsonResponse.getJSONObject(i);
            clients[i] = obj.getString("client_id");
            status[i] = obj.getBoolean("payed");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show us code from the Android app. How are you getting the data from your PHP backend? We need more code to help

Comment: Thank you, question updated with android code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually figure it out, i just send my data in my PHP file like this:

```
$statement = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT client_id,Payed FROM reservations WHERE resto_id = '$restaurantID'");

$response = array();


while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($statement)){
    $response[]=$row;
            $response[]=$row;
}         


echo json_encode($response);
```

And i get the data from android like this:

```
Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    System.out.println(response);
                    try {
                        JSONArray jsonResponse = new JSONArray(response);
                        System.out.println("JSON LENGTH =" + jsonResponse.length());

                        String[] clients = new String[jsonResponse.length()];
                        String[] status = new String[jsonResponse.length()];

                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonResponse.length(); i++) {

                            JSONObject obj = jsonResponse.getJSONObject(i);
                            clients[i] = obj.getString("client_id");
                            status[i] = obj.getString("Payed");
                        }
```

I'll be glad if it could help someone.